# How do I query saved wireless profiles?

Tags: c#, api, wifi

I have used both Batch and shell scripts to accomplish this, however, the fact that I have to go one by one through the saved xml files is a bit tedious.

I am trying to find a way to accomplish this through the NativeWifi API (found here  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35329/How-to-access-wireless-network-parameters-using-na)) However all I get are the available wireless access points and their signal strength.

**Current goal for this question:** retrieve saved wireless profiles in a folder **if** a physical wireless adapter exists.

BATCH FILE:

```
set wlanfld="WirelessProfiles"
if not exist %wlanfld% md %wlanfld%
echo off
netsh wlan export profile folder=%wlanfld% key=clear
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %wlanfld% %%a in (*.xml) do (
set oldName=%%~xna
set newName=!oldName:~28!
ren "%%a" "!newName!"
)
```

Then here is a snippet of the code.

```
    private void wifiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox2.Text = "";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\\Users\jpearson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ComplianceGuide\ComplianceGuide\wifi.bat");
        Process.Start(@"c:\\Users\jpearson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ComplianceGuide\ComplianceGuide\bin\Debug\WirelessProfiles");


        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIFace in client.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIFace.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);

            foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                wifiBox.Text += String.Format("{0}                                                    Signal Quality {1}" + Environment.NewLine, GetString(network.dot11Ssid), network.wlanSignalQuality);

            }

        }            
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I kind of threw this up haha, I didn't realize the little redundancies in the text.